# what's the difference between spatial and temporal characterization in terms of image processing?

Tags: java, python, image, matlab, image-processing

I am a beginner in learning image processing and I am a bit confused with the concept of spatial and temporal characterization.  So, for Spatial characterization, is it like a 2D map which contains some statistical information about the map?  And in terms of the temporal characterization, is the value with respect to time?  What does it mean and why do we care?  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Temporal characterization occurs when you have a series of images taken at different time. Correlations between the images are often used to monitor the dynamic changes of the object.

Spatial characterization applies when you are analyzing one image. It includes but not limited to the coordinates, intensity, gradient, resolution, to name only a few.

Check this paper on [blood vessel analysis](http://www.siue.edu/~sumbaug/RetinalProjectPapers/Spatio-temporal%20characterization%20of%20vessel%20segments%20applied%20to%20retinal%20angiographic%20images.pdf) to get more details among the two.

Comment: thank you very much for your response!  I am much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Spatial = Space
Example, Image consist of pixel values which needs memory space to store. Spatial information = Pixel values stored into Memory
Temporal = Time
Example, Video consists of image frame sequence. With respect to time the frames are changed in video. This is called Temporal Information.

Answer (score 0):

Example of Spatial analysis application: Inspecting an image e.g. pose estimation on an image.

Example of Temporal analysis application: Inspecting a video e.g. vehicle monitoring or pedestrian path prediction