# What is the definition of the terms SPATIAL and TEMPORAL in terms of statistics, data science or machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, spatial, data-science, temporal

What is the exact definition of spatial and temporal? I saw in many places people use these two terms, e.g., spatial vector, temporal vector, temporal factor, spatial location.

I was searching in StackOverflow, and found this one- [what's the difference between spatial and temporal characterization in terms of image processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818230/whats-the-difference-between-spatial-and-temporal-characterization-in-terms-of)

What I understood so far is that the term spatial is related to space and the term temporal is related to time. Still, it is quite abstract to me. Again, I am also not sure about the uses of these two. So, as same as the person asked in the above link, I want to ask the same question- What do these two terms mean and why do we care about these two?

Answer (score 7):

Spatial data have to do with location-aware information, in other words, data that have coordinates `(x, y)`. A typical example of spatial data is latitude and longitude in geographic datasets. Spatial analyses are the techniques involved in analyzing spatial data. This is a significant component of GIS (Geographic Information Systems/Science)

Temporal data is time-series data. In other words, this is data that is collected as time progresses. Temporal analysis is also known as Time-Series analysis. These are the techniques for analyzing data units that change with time.

I hope this makes these concepts less abstract and more concrete.

Comment: Does that mean if we remove the time from a time-series data it would be considered as spatial?

Comment: Then the data becomes stationary like regular historical data.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Ekaba's answer, spatial data doesn't necessarily need to be two dimensional either. I'm going to take an example from a medical domain which would have both spatial and temporal elements of data.

If you consider magnetic resonance imaging, it is essentially a 3D Volumetric view of an organ (let's say brain for clarity). So if you are to analyse a traditional MRI, it would be spatial analysis and you'll have 3 dimensions as it is 3D. There's another MRI modality called DCE-MRI which is essentially a sequence of MRI volumes captured over time. Now this is a typical example of a temporal sequence. Let's say DCE-MRI sequence has 40 MRI volumes captured 20s apart from each. If you just consider one sequence out of these 40 and analyse that, you'll be analyzing it spatially whereas if you consider all 40 (or a subset) of these volumes at the same time, you are analyzing it spatially as well as temporally.

Hope that clarifies things.

Comment: Does that mean if we remove the time from a time-series data it would be considered as spatial?

Comment: that is correct, then it just becomes on instance of a time series that you are looking at and in isolation, can be considered as a spatial instance

Answer (score 0):

Another similar medical example is ultrasound imaging of a beating heart (2D Echocardiography) where the ultrasound image shows opening and closing movement of heart valves in real-time and volumetric movement of heart chambers. With high temporal resolution (@ 30 frames per second) it is easy to follow the valves opening and closing  accurately. With high spatial resolution it is also easy to differentiate boarders of the heart chambers to provide accurate volumetric blood flow data.